# nginx rewrite url with if and arg

Tags: nginx, rewrite

Trying to use a wildcard redirect here but unable to figure out what to set for the wildcard, example:

URL: example.com/search?q=broccoli 
Redirect to: example.com/?s=broccoli

broccoli can be anything

code:

```
location /search {
  if ($arg_q) {
  return 301 https://example.com/?s=$1;
  }
}
```

The result is example.com/?s=

not sure what 'variable' I have to use in place of $1

I was thinking maybe having to do something like

```
location /search {
  if ($arg_q = (.*)) {
  return 301 https://example.com/?s=$1;
  }
}
```

but no luck there either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to use the value of q, then you just use that value, the same as you already did!

```
location /search {
    if ($arg_q) {
        return 301 https://example.com/?s=$arg_q;
    }
}
```